# Nuget restore on monodevelop Ubuntu - references seem to not work?

Tags: nuget, monodevelop, nuget-package-restore

After restoring nugets on Monodevelop / Ubuntu the packages are all there but the projects complain that there isn't a DLL for the version:

```
Assembly not found for Framework Mono / .Net4.5
```

This code works on other machines so i know the references are correct.

Also - looking in the CSPROJ I can see the references are resolved to dlls in the packages folder. So everything downloaded OK.

I have set MonoDevelop to use MSBuild as there was a similar post somewhere but that's not working.

Is there a trick to getting this to work?

Comment: Which dll is not found? Does that dll exist in the packages directory? Is the hintPath correct? Are you using a custom repositoryPath? Does closing and re-opening the solution fix the problem?

Comment: Hi, yeah the DLLs are there, the hint path is correct. It seems to be random but 90% of the DLLs installed by NuGet seem to not be happy. I'm compiling Monodevelop from source to see if v5 works

Comment: Still trying to figure this out - had a pain with mozroots building from source on vagrant box! While I have you though, is there a way to add a repo source to Monodevelop Nuget via terminal?

Comment: If you have NuGet.exe you can add a repo source using `nuget sources add -Name [name] -Source [source]`. NuGet.exe is shipped with Mono 3.8 or above. Otherwise the official NuGet.exe should work or you can get one for Mono from GitHub - https://github.com/mono/nuget-binary

Comment: Will that add it into the sources for md? Are they stored globally?

Comment: Yes it will add it globally so it will be visible in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Aha, had to su as vagrant runs bootstrap.sh as root - working like a charm!!